# Load external javascript file and create iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, frontend

I need to create a javascript that return a iframe tag.
the customer will paste a script in where the iframe need to be, and then the script should create a iframe.

Must be like this:

```
<script src="http://www.helloworld.com/script/loadcustomerframe.js" data-customer="14532"></script>
```

then the script should load a iframe to a url somewhere, and also i need to read the "data-customer".

I am a backend developer c#, not a frontend. I have try several days now, i cant get it to work.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("[data-customer]").each(function() {
    let customerId = $(this).data("customer");
    $(this).replaceWith(`<p>This is customer #${customerId}.</p>`);
    // The following comment is an example of how you could use an iframe
    //$(this).replaceWith(`<iframe src="http://example.org/customer/${customerId}>Hello!</iframe>`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-customer="1"></div>
<div data-customer="2"></div>
<div data-customer="3"></div>
```

You'll only need to have the script appear once (most likely in your `<head>`) and it will replace any `<div>` that has a `data-customer` attribute. You simply just need to figure out the proper URL for your `<iframe>`.

Answer (score -2):

Si basically your JS code will do the trick,

First need to create a JS code and host it into some server to get it by fetching it, so image that your JS code is hosted into `https://www.mygreatjscode.com/myjscode.js`

So your JS code will do the rest,

like this using pure JS (with not frameworks like jQuery etc), so your `myjscode.js` file will contain this:

```
//create an autoexec function
(function(){
    var body = document.getElementByTagName("body");
     body = body ? body : false;

     if (body){
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
         iframe.setAttribute("id", "MY_CUSTOM_ID");
          //here set the url that the iframe will be render
          iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://stackoverflow.com/");
          //finally insert into the body of page
          body.appendChild(iframe);
     }

 })();
```

Finally you need to insert the Script Tag into your page like this

```
<script src="https://www.mygreatjscode.com/myjscode.js" data-customer="14532"></script>
```